# I'm trying to install django in virtual environment but getting some error and I don't understand what is it about

Tags: python, django

```
> pip install django  
     
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-4.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.1/8.1 MB 24.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.5.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      /private/var/folders/z_/gh45f3y971vg11kt0m32cl440000gn/T/pip-build-env-tklngwk1/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/harshitdubey/Documents/greendeck/django_files/connect-django/.connect/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**My python version**

> Python 3.8.9

**I've tried things like**

> **python -m pip install django**

> **pip install django==4.0.0**

***but stll can't find any solution.***

I have two python versions in my macos I don't thing that's causing the error. Any help will be appreciated.
I have already updated my pip version which is 22.2.2

Comment: what is version of the other python?

Comment: that one is python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your python versions. Before reinstalling completely remove it from control panel > uninstall and also remove from C drive then install again and then try